# не корректно работает hover эффект

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

[image: на данном фото ховер применился только к изображению, но это работает не правильно. Хотелось добиться применения и к фото и к тексту .]

```css
.features {
  width: 510px;
  margin: 0 auto 30px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.features p {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0 5px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center top;
  text-align: center;
}

.feature-furniture {
  padding-top: 65px;
}

.feature-lighting {
  padding-top: 65px;
}

.feature-accessories {
  padding-top: 65px;
}

.features-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  transition: .2s;
}

.features-image {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.features-card p {
  display: block;
}

.features-text {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.features-card:hover {
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 13px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  transition: .2s;
}

.features-card {
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="features-wrapper">
  <div>

    <div class="features-image"><img class="features-card" src="img/male1.png"></div>
    <div class="features-text">Для Мужчин</div>
  </div>

  <div class="features-card">
    <div><img src="img/accesuc.png"></div>
    <p>Для Женщин</p>
  </div>


  <div class="features-card">
    <div><img src="img/woman2.png"></div>
    <p>Аксессуары</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Что конкретно неправильно работает? Опишите нормально проблему. Скорее всего Вам нужно `.features-card:hover > div { /*стили при наведении*/ }`, чтобы при наведении на всю карточку затеняло только блок картинки?

Comment: hover эффект применяется только к фото. а хочется добиться- и к фото и к тексту.

Comment: Ну вот селектор выше, будет применяться

Comment: Попробуйте поместить текст в блок картинки.

Comment: так он уже есть в коде. Но не затрагивает текст.

Comment: Где есть, когда нет ничего?

Comment: [![Что выводит](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKlny.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKlny.png) Вы этого результата пытаетесь добиться ?

Comment: всем благодарность за отклик. Ошибка была в том,что увлекся дивами + оформил код криво и сам себя запутал.
Теперь все работает как хотел. ps/извиняюсь за плохое изложение проблемы.

Answer (score 1):

Так вы хотели?
Теперь hover захватывает текст.

Мне интересно, для верстки вы использовали bootstrap?

Если мой ответ помог, то пожалуйста пометьте это как ответ =)

```css
.features {
  width: 510px;
  margin: 0 auto 30px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.features p {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0 5px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center top;
  text-align: center;
}

.feature-furniture {
  padding-top: 65px;
}

.feature-lighting {
  padding-top: 65px;
}

.feature-accessories {
  padding-top: 65px;
}

.features-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  transition: .2s;
}

.features-image {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.features-card p {
  display: block;
}

.features-text {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.features-card:hover {
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 13px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  transition: .2s;
}

.features-card {
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class ="features-wrapper">

    <div class="features-card">
    <img src="img/male1.png">
    <p>Для Мужчин</p>
  </div>

  <div class="features-card">
  <img src="img/accesuc.png">
    <p>Для Женщин</p>
  </div>


  <div class="features-card">
   <img src="img/woman2.png">
    <p>Аксессуары</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

В секции `div` "Для мужчин" вы добавили `class="features-card"` к изображению (в 4-ю строчку), поэтому он охватывает только изображение, а надо его написать во 2-ю, так же как у вас сделано для двух других секций.